# Can't install Unity game on my Android device

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, android-sdk-2.3, android-api-levels

I just built my Unity game for android. But when I wanted to install this apk on my phone - occurred an error:

[image]

From my language, it translates like `"The app is not installed because it is not compatible with your phone"`.

I thought it could be a problem with target API level parameter. I changed it for: **min. API Level - Android 5.1; target API level - API level 34.** I've also tried with **target API level Android 13.0.** In all cases it didn't helped.

If you need this, ***my phone is Google Pixel 7 on Android 13.***

I've also tested on another devices like:

- Some Xiaomi (Android 13)
- Poco m3 (Android 12)
- Realme 13 (Android13)

And on these devices it **installed successful.**

Do you have any ideas what may help me?

Comment: Try to install via adb, you can get a detailed reason. BTW pixel 7 only supports 64-bit app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed!

I tried to fix these 3 days, and after less than half an hour after posting this fixed by myself.

The problem was that my phone had different architecture, that wasn't checked in Other Settings in Unity. I checked it, and everything worked now.

[image]